# invocation of ant script before execution of maven "scanning of projects"

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, maven-plugin, tycho

I wanted to change the project contents **based on the corresponding maven profile specified**. In this regard I wanted to integrate a ant script as a part of profile. I got to know how to integrate ant script from the following site https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-ant.html.

> But I need to replace contents before scanning of projects by maven which currently is not happening.

In this regard I am not sure which life-cycle-phase should I specify for the maven-antrun-plugin execution (*currently I have specified the phase as validate*)

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? And what kind of content are you trying to change and for what purpose?

Comment: As the question is flagged with `tycho`, please note that Tycho won’t see any modifications to `MANIFEST.MF`, `build.properties`, etc. made at a later point during the build. **But** I second khmarbaise: What are you trying to accomplish. This looks highly unusual.